# modify the min length for the "People or Group" auto complete

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

i have a "People or Group" field inside my team site, and currently the built-in autocomplete will work after typing 3 characters. so how i can modify this to allow the autocomplete to work after typing the first character .

second question does the autocomplete API allow returning all the results ?

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-minLength and http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: @EricAlexander thanks for the links. ok if i am writing my own autocomplete i know how to use these settings. but my question is how i can apply these settings to work with the built-in autocomplete ? i mean to override its default behavior inside sharepoint?

Comment: @EricAlexander for example if i write $( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
  minLength: 0
});
 inside my master page will not have any effect.. on the people or group autocomplete..

Comment: @EricAlexander also i tried the follwoing inside my master page <script  type="text/javascript">
 $.ajaxSetup({
  $( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
  minLength: 1
});});</script>
 but will not have any effect..

Comment: @EricAlexander can u advice further on how i can apply the links to work on sharepoint ?

Comment: you tagged the question, are you using jquey ui or not?

Comment: @EricAlexander yes i have a reference to both jquery and jquery ui scripts inside my master page as follow:- <SharePoint:CustomJSUrl runat="server" />
 <script  type="text/javascript" src="/Style%20Library/JS/jquery-1.10.2.js" ></script>
 <script  type="text/javascript" src="/Style%20Library/JS/jquery-ui.js" ></script>

Comment: @EricAlexander now i edit the clientpeoplepicker,js & clientpeoplepicker.debug scripts under the ""C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS" an i chnage the "AutoFillMinTextLength" from 3 to 1, where the autocomplete for the people search will start after typing 1 character instead of 3 characters. but if i set it to be 0 , then the autocomplete will not return all the results when i move the mouse over it..

Comment: I don't see what jQuery UI has to do with this, you are modifying system files, so you don't appear to be using autocomplete at all and are customizing the ootb field.

Comment: @EricAlexander i did not say that i do not want to use jquery-ui,, i am trying to find options to modify the built-in settings,,, if this can be done using jquery-ui then i do not have any problem..

Comment: @EricAlexander can you advice further on how i can change the built-in settings using jquery-ui ?

Comment: You can't just hijack the built in people picker with jQuery UI, it requires mark up specified in their API.

Comment: @EricAlexander ok i got your point, now i edit the clientpeoplepicker.js and i change this parameters "this.AutoFillControl.AutoFillMinTextLength = 3" to be "this.AutoFillControl.AutoFillMinTextLength = 0" and this will force the autocomplete to work when users start typing the first character (instead of 3),, which solved one problem... now what i am trying to achieve is to be able to view all the autocomplete available items without any filtering,, not sure if such a modification is supported ?